# how to prevent links from styling their children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm re-developing a website and I'd like to have simple links in the menu, so that the user can open them in new tabs, a menu item looks like this at the moment:

```
<li class='menu-left-row' id='messages' onclick=\"javascript:showscreen_load('messages.php?sel=overview','messages','menu-left')\">
    <div class='menu-left-picture'>
    <img src='IMG/menu-left-messages.png'>
    </div>
    <div class='menu-left-item'>
    Messages
    </div>
</li>
```

now what i set up a function that intersepts all links with the class 'toggle_reconstruct' and so i'd like to have it rather something like this:

```
<li class='menu-left-row' id='messages'>
    <div class='menu-left-picture'>
    <img src='IMG/menu-left-messages.png'>
    </div>
    <div class='menu-left-item'>
    <a class='toggle_reconstruct' href='/messages/'>Messages</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

but now the link is styling the text of the menu item, in this case "messages" becomes bold and blue. there will be lots of other menu items with a lot of different styles, is there any way to prevent the link from styling its content?

UPDATE: 
someone just pointed me to use:

```
a:link {font-weight:inherit; color:inherit;text-decoration:none;}
```

would this be a valid option?

Comment: could you show us the function?

Comment: `li` elements can only be inside of `ul`, `ol`, `dir`, and `menu `elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/li Invalid html leads to inconsistent and sometimes unexplainable behavior down the road.

Comment: @KevinB thanks for the heads up, i already refitted the code, so have the link inside the <li>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either move the div outside of the `a` tag or apply a class to it and give it a custom style (overriding the style given by the link). So in this case, you might want to add some CSS to the `menu-left-item` class so it looks like however you want.

Comment: that's what i thought... I just wasn't sure, if there was a way to somehow disable the a tag from styling its children

Comment: someone just pointed me to use: a:link {font-weight:inherit; color:inherit;text-decoration:none;} --- would this be a valid option?

Comment: You'll also want to style `a:visited` to the same, otherwise it'll be purple after the user clicks it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the direct descendant sign in CSS to prevent styling from cascading past the first level

```
.nav > li {background-color: #ccc;}
```

*Will not work on IE6*

Comment: Wouldn't this still cause all items below the anchor tag to have the same font color as an anchor tag?

Answer (score 1):

just add a style like this:

```
<style>
a.toggle_reconstruct {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
```

Is this what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent the children from inheriting by two ways.

**Adding a class:**

If you have a nested list, then this would be a problem. You wanna give a background for the main list but not the sublist, then give the main list a class.

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="main">Home</li>
    <li class="main">
        About
        <ul>
            <li>Products</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li>Corporate</li>
    </li>
<ul>
```

And the CSS as:

```
.nav .main {background-color: #ccc;}
```

**By specificity operator:**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>
        About
        <ul>
            <li>Products</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
            <li>Corporate</li>
    </li>
<ul>
```

And the CSS as:

```
.nav > li {background-color: #ccc;}
```

***Note:** The specificity method doesn't work in IE 6!*

Hope this helps. :)